# Type of memory used to design Arbitrary Waveform Generators (AWGs)

Tags: digital-logic, analog, signal-processing, memory

i am interested in understanding how the design decision is taken while choosing the type of memory to be used in AWGs. My understanding is that in most AWGs, waveforms are stored in a Digital memory such as DRAM/SRAM and a DAC is used to convert to an analog signal

Is it possible for anyone to share some insight into why that is the case and why it won't be efficient to use say an analog memory that doesn't require a DAC?

Any inputs are appreciated

Comment: What analog memory do you have in mind?

Comment: Actually, that's part of my question. There must be a reason as to why analog memory is not considered an option for such applications. Is it because they are not fast enough, and have a lot of noise?

Comment: Define analog memory? Why would it be used? Like cassette tape or LP record with prerecorded waveforms?

Comment: @Justme By analog memory, I mean an array of CMOS-based storage elements that are capable of holding a range of values and not just 0V or 2.5V. Something like what is shown here : https://www.iee.et.tu-dresden.de/iee/analog/papers/mirror/visionchips/vision_chips/analog_memories.html

Comment: How would you program the analog waveform into analog memory? With a DAC?

Comment: I am not an expert in the area, but I am guessing DAC could be used to program

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi: The link that you provided to Justme actually answers your question.

Comment: @RussellH They do talk about the various drawbacks associated with analog memory, but there isn't a direct comparison between, say, memory access cost of analog memory (with better leakage circuit) vs digital memory. I am just curious if I can find something of that sort

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi which sense would it have to have a DAC that can fill analog memory, which is a very finnicky and slow technology, instead of just feeding the DAC live from digital memory? I mean, you're the one proposing something very unusual: you should have some arguments *for* it, but so far you only show a very superficial understanding of what this analog storage cell does – you haven't considered even how you'll be playing back a sequential signal from a large array of such analog memory cells (hint: that's going to end up looking a lot *like* a DAC, but without the digital advantages).

Comment: You're filling your analog memory with a DAC, so your signal is still quantized in amplitude. You're still using discrete time steps to record and play back the signal. So even with an ideal setup you get exactly the same output from your analog memory setup as you'd get from a digital memory serving a DAC. Your proposal gives you all the problems of dealing with analog memory and no advantages whatsoever.

Comment: @brhans and Marcus, thank you for your response. I would like to clarify that I am in no way suggesting my method as an alternative to be used. It is more of a curious question for me. I am not sure what type of analog memory one would if one had to use them in AWGs. I am just hoping to understand how much of a difference there might be in performance if one uses an Analog Memory as compared to a Digital Mem + DAC